# Is python/matplotlib just plotting the real part of the complex equation here without my prompting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, complex-numbers

I am analyzing some code, and there's an equation containing imaginary and real parts, and that's being plotted without any prompting about the imaginary or real part:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
pi = np.pi

k = 2*pi*1e6
k_e = 2*pi*400e3

w_0 = 10.607e9
w_s = np.linspace(8e9, 12e9)

S11_Ideal = 1 - (2*k_e)/(k + 2j*(w_s - w_0))
plt.plot(w_s,S11_Ideal)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]
From output it seem like the real part is being plotted. Is that's what happening? I just want some confirmation that it's just straight up ignoring the imaginary part of the numbers here or is there something else that's going on?

Answer (score 2):

I think it throws below error when you run your code :

```sh
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:83: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

This warning is coming from the `plot` command. "plot" is meant to take a 1d, real array and put it on the screen. When it sees an array of complex numbers it does the best it can, i.e. discards the imaginary part and plot the real part.

You can plot both `components` separately. refer below code for more details if you want to plot both parts.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
pi = np.pi

k = 2*pi*1e6
k_e = 2*pi*400e3

w_0 = 10.607e9
w_s = np.linspace(8e9, 12e9)

S11_Ideal = 1 - (2*k_e)/(k + 2j*(w_s - w_0))
plt.plot(w_s,S11_Ideal.real, 'b', label="real")
plt.plot(w_s,S11_Ideal.imag, 'r', label="imag")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Output Image:**

[image]

I would suggest you to look at [this tutorial](https://www.epythonguru.com/2019/12/Plot-Complex-Number-in-Python.html).